# Add `Copy to Clipboard` button on the menu for `share` on a Question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sharing

When you tap on the `share` button, under a question, at the bottom it has 3 options to share. I suggest that this menu should also have an option to copy the URL to clipboard.

Comment: Why don't you just copy it yourself? It's already highlighted, just a Ctrl+C would do it.

Comment: @user202729: Because some people use phones/tablets, where Ctrl+C doesn't exist.

Comment: @NicolBolas Then how can you paste? Holding the text and choose [Copy] is no harder than holding {a textbox} and choose [Paste].

Comment: @user202729: Maybe where they want to paste has a button labeled "paste". Or "take from clipboard". And at least with a copy button, they only need to do the hold trick *once*.

Comment: @user202729 for convenience. why click share when you can copy the url yourself and post it on whatever network manually? So, if you are already using the mouse to click on share, why switch to the keyboard to copy when you can just keep using the mouse for that too?

Comment: @Adelin I suppose this only applies for those who use the mouse most of the time. / Besides that doesn't work with answers.

Comment: @NicolBolas I use a phone all the time; to copy the share url you can just tap-hold the 'share' link and select "copy link address", and done.

Comment: The trouble with copying the URL directly from a browser's address bar is that you're also copying -- and then sharing -- parameters like `?cb=1` (to pick a simple example from my current address bar).  And while that specific parameter is harmless, others might break whatever the _recipient_ of the pasted URL is trying to do.  Expecting the share-er to know what to trim is probably too much, and it's tedious to do on a mobile device in any case.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, don't copy from address bar. The `share` button link is personalized and shorter, you are loosing benefits.

Comment: @Sinatr I never mentioned the address bar. Which part of "tap-hold the share link" says "copy the url from the address bar"?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, ignore your name in my comment please. I've read the last comment and quickly decide TiStrga was answering you, this is why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature has been implemented. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the "share" popup, there is a new option introduced as "copy link".

> [image: share popup]

When clicking on the link, the link is copied to clipboard.

> [image: Copied to clipboard]

Comment: Were the Twitter and Facebook icons there before?

Comment: [Yes, it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316878/312043)